# LibGit2Sharp CheckoutPaths()

Tags: git, repository, git-checkout, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I did a commit (49916.....) now i want to checkout one file of the commit into the working dir. The file is named NEW.txt. 
If i type

> Git checkout 49916 NEW.txt

into Git Bash it creates the NEW.txt file with the content in my working dir.

But my LibGit2Sharp command does not want to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
       var repo = new Repository(repopath);
       var checkoutPaths = new[] { "NEW.txt"};    
       repo.CheckoutPaths("49916", checkoutPaths);
```

I read every article which i could find about the checkoutpaths function. But i cant get it working. I got the function from the LibGit2Sharp checkout test file.

```
            repo.CheckoutPaths(checkoutFrom, new[] { path });
```

Comment: Beside @jamill's question, what is the state of your workdir before the call to CheckoutPaths()? Does the file exist?

Comment: I tested both. So with the file existing and without. Now both cases work. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What happens when you run that code? Does it run to completion but there are no changes in the working directory? What happens if you try to checkout with the `CheckoutModifiers.Force` option?

```
CheckoutOptions options = new CheckoutOptions { CheckoutModifiers = CheckoutModifiers.Force };
repo.CheckoutPaths("49916", checkoutPaths, options);
```

Comment: It ran to completion but without changes in the working dir. Your awnser solves my problem. I was missing the options. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue.Code run to completion, but there were no changes in the working directory.
The reason was my `checkoutPaths` collection.

I've passed file path relative to app directory instead of path **relative to repository itself**.

E.g.

Wrong path:
`Repositories/MyRepo/MyFile.txt`

Correct path:
`MyFile.txt`