# LibGit2Sharp CheckoutPaths() to Revert a File without specifying a Branch

Tags: git, git-checkout, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I would like to do the equivalent of `git checkout -- file` to discard changes in a file not yet staged for commit.

I have seen the question around [how to checkout from a specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22254932/libgit2sharp-checkoutpaths), however I don't want to specify any specific commit or branch.

In the following code, the parameter for `commitishOrBranchSpec` appears to be required, but cannot be null or an empty string; is there a value that can be specified here that indicates `default`, similar to the lack of specifying any branch or commit in the git command line above?

```
using (var repo = new Repository(workingDir))
{
    // $TODO: Figure out what to pass for parameter 1,
    // commitishOrBranchSpec (null and "" don't work)
    repo.CheckoutPaths("", Enumerable.Repeat(filePath, 1));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have seen the question around how to checkout from a specific commit, however I don't want to specify any specific commit or branch.

You must specify something to checkout.  If you want to emulate `git checkout -- file`, then you can simply use the `HEAD` branch.  For example:

```
repo.checkoutPaths(repo.Head, new string[] { filePath }, checkoutOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks- looks like `repo.Head.FriendlyName` (which ends up being the string 'master' in this case), was successful.